# Make RSS feed of a page that has no feed

Tags: rss

How would I go about if I want to create an RSS feed of a page that basically is or has no RSS feed?

I really enjoy reading a random article on the [Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) and How [Stuff Works](http://www.howstuffworks.com). Unfortunately there is no RSS for these special pages. I tried using IFTTT to send me a random article once daily, which worked great, but I would prefer to have this stuff in my feed reader rather than my mailbox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is [feed43](http://feed43.com/) an option for you? If not, [here](http://techpp.com/2009/04/27/top-10-free-tools-to-create-rss-for-any-website-2/) is a collection of other sites which is listing more alternatives.

Comment: Actually, no. Have you looked at the sites I mentioned or read my question? The sites do not only have no feed, but I am looking for a way to check these URL's once daily, otherwise I would get about 20 new random articles every day.